# Ruby - incrementally assign the output of a block to an undeclared variable

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to Ruby and a few times lately I've needed to do something like the following:

**1)** Declare a variable **2)** Do stuff to variable **3)** Return variable

when I feel I should be able to

**1)** Do stuff while assigning it incrementally to a variable which is then returned

To illustrate what I mean the example below generates a random hex color. 
I feel this should be a one liner but I'm not sure how.

```
# This example generates a random color 
color = "#"
6.times { color << "ABCDEF0123456789".chars.sample }
color #= "#ABC123"


# The above code seems cumbersome & what I want to do this
"#" << 6.times { color << "ABCDEF0123456789".chars.sample } #= "#\u0006"
```

I've tried lots of variations of this with no success. Is there a way I can do this? Is the times loop the wrong approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to do what you're asking is something like:

```
"#" + 6.times.map { "ABCDEF0123456789".chars.sample }.join
```

But it might be more correct and easier to do something like:

```
format "#%02x%02x%02x", rand(255), rand(255), rand(255)
```

Or:

```
require 'securerandom'
"#" + SecureRandom.hex(3)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. And thanks for the additional examples too, I'll have a read up on them.

Comment: A hex color is just 3x (r, g, and b) 1-byte values (0-255) encoded as a pair of hexadecimal digits (16^2 = 256). To generate a random color, you can generate 3 values in the 0-255 range and convert each to a hex pair.

Comment: Is the middle one the same as `format "#%06x", rand(256*256*256-1)
 #=> "#dfc29d"`?

Comment: It should be noted that #2 could be written using [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) or [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25), rather than [Kernel#format](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format). (All share the same format string.) For example: `"#%06x" % rand(256*256*256-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write:

```
"##{ 'Magpie'.gsub(/./) { |c| rand(16).to_s(16) } }"
  #=> "#b1a501"
```

Tack on `.upcase` if for some reason you want `"#B1A501"`.